# How to fix transition animation on click CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I work with search bar, and i want to make it nice, but for some reason transition animation is not working for me, i try to use few methods but only `animation css` is help example:

```
.active {
    width: 100%;
    outline: none !important;
    z-index: 901;
    border: 1px solid #30a161 !important;
    animation: animateRight .6s ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateRight {
    0% {
        width: 100px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

But transition method for me it's better, so what i want, i have animation hiding body, animation of closing input for search (opening animation i have) maybe better solution to move to transition.

```
.search_modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
    transition: top 1s ease; // here should be animation
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/tcwb53pj/14/)

So i want 2 animation, first when added class **.search_modal** it;s moving to *-50 on top* and when closing again need animation, and input opening and closing.

Comment: If you want the animation to run on click, then you should only append the class that adds the `animation` property on click. Also, the fiddle you've shared is massive: try sharing a minimal, concrete and verifiable example instead. It contains a ton of unnecessary and irrelevant markup and styles.

Comment: @Terry i just fixed jsfiddle, and can u provide some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the transition property on the element before you transition and make your transition class more specific. The following snippert should do the trick

```
header .search_container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  z-index: 1024;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 1s ease; //Add it here
}

header .search_container.search_modal {
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
}
```